# PHP function that creates a nested ul li?

Tags: php, css, function

I am attemptting to attach a small CMS to a website I am creating. However I have come across a small problem. The CMS uses PHP functions for inserting menus, these PHP functions create the HTML. The particular function I wish to use (treemenu) creates a nested ul li that can then be used for a drop down menu. However the nested ul li is structured like so:

```
<li>Projects (Menu Level 1)</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Project 1 (Menu Level 2)</li>
        <li>Project 2 (Menu Level 2)</li>
        <li>Project 3 (Menu Level 2)</li>
    </ul>
<li>News (Menu Level 1)</li>
<li>Contact (Menu Level 1)</li>
```

When creating a drop down menu in CSS I believe the Menu Level 1 li should wrap its children like so:

```
<li>Projects (Menu Level 1)
    <ul>
        <li>Project 1 (Menu Level 2)</li>
        <li>Project 2 (Menu Level 2)</li>
        <li>Project 3 (Menu Level 2)</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>News (Menu Level 1)</li>
<li>Contact (Menu Level 1)</li>
```

I have never before worked with PHP and therefore would not know how to alter the function in order to accomplish the above. I would hope it would be a simple change. Below is the PHP function that outputs the first example structure:

```
function treemenu($generat=0) {
global $pagenum, $menu, $selected, $extension, $set;
$count=0;
$out="\n";
$intend=0;
while($menu[$count][0] != "") {
    if(strpos($menu[$count][3],"#") === false) {
    if($menu[$count][2]=="0" && $intend==2) {
        $intend--;
        $out.="</ul>\n";
    }
    if($menu[$count][1]=="0" && $intend==1) {
        $intend--;
        $out.="</ul>\n";
    }
    if($menu[$count][1]!="0" && $intend<1) {
        $intend=1;
        $out.="<ul>\n";
    }
    if($menu[$count][2]!="0" && $intend<2) {
        $intend=2;
        $out.="<ul>\n";
    }
    $out.="<li class=\"LNE_menu\"><a ";
    if($menu[$count][4]==$selected['name'])
        $out.= 'class="selected" ';
    if(strpos($menu[$count][3],"*"))
        $out.='href="'.str_replace("*", "",$menu[$count][3]).'">';
    elseif($generat)
        $out.='href="'.$menu[$count][3].".".$set['extension'].'">';
    else
        $out.='href="'.$set['indexfile'].'?page='.$menu[$count][3].'">';
    $out.=$menu[$count][4]."</a></li>\n";
    }
    $count++;
}
return $out;
}
```

Could anyone possibly point me in the right direction as to how to make the closing li tag of a level 1 menu item wrap the ul immediately after, as in the second example?

Comment: Bejesuz that's ugly! Whomever wrote that should be flogged.

Comment: A good example of bad PHP, perhaps someone can help redeem this by proividing some good PHP.

Comment: Haha! Do you think that what I am after is a small change to that code?

Comment: not a small change - just a small, recursive function.

Comment: that looks like a project for ... captain recursion!

i'd help you (writing a function that does what you want is easy), but it would be better if i knew more about the data structure you're using.

Comment: Hello Schnalle, i'm sorry I don't even know what you mean by data structure. Do I need to provide more info in order for this question to be answered? I originally hoped I could simply switch the order of the code! Silly me.

Comment: i'm just too lazy to reverse engineer the treemenu function

Comment: This is where you give me many points.

Comment: I'm really grateful for your help Topbit, but I am worried about simply dropping your BEAUTIFUL code into the CMS PHP file as I'm sure it would create more problems that I would not have a clue about! which is why I was hoping it would be a simple tweak of the original file. I need to learn PHP!

Comment: I understand now that the PHP above is not great however, I would rather not create a new function because I do not have the knowledge to do so. One last possibility, could the </li>\n be moved from the final line elsewhere and solve my problem. Fingers Crossed.

Comment: i tried to understand the treemenu function, now i'm feeling dizzy and hungover. please, get rid of that cms as fast as possible. it represents everything thats wrong with php and programming.

Comment: How does your data structure look like?

Comment: add a "var_dump($menu);" after the global (without the quotes of course) and post the result. a var_dump of the other values ($pagenum, $selected, $extension, $set) would be helpful too. then we might be able to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by data structure?

Comment: I have added "var_dump($menu)" and uploaded the file back to the server Schnelle. Where can I find the results?

Comment: @Ronnie: What is the data you are generating this list from? How does that look like, how is that data structured?

Comment: in this case, the data structure is how the variable $menu looks like (how it's structured). you can show us by var_exporting it.

Comment: Ok, go to the website, login to the CMS. The CMS admin panel then allows me to do certain things, one of which is add a page. If I add a page it then uses this function to create the list item and the hyperlink, I then style this using css.

Comment: if you reload the page, it should be right there. i hope, it's not a live production server. if it is, remove it immediately. but first, look at the html source code around the menu, there should be contents that doesn't belong there. that's what we're looking for.

Comment: Just found this in the PHP file in which the treemenu function is: 
// $menu - contains the menu
$menu=array(array('m1','m2','m3','link','name','descr','templ'));

Comment: Here's the result of the var_dump: array(4) { [0]=>  array(7) { [0]=>  string(1) "1" [1]=>  string(1) "0" [2]=>  string(1) "0" [3]=>  string(5) "index" [4]=>  string(4) "Home" [5]=>  string(1) "-" [6]=>  string(1) "-" } [1]=>  array(7) { [0]=>  string(1) "1" [1]=>  string(1) "1&qu

Comment: sorry, i give up. the guy who wrote the cms is a complete amateur, and the code is HORRIBLE! it's beyond evil. i really recommend switching to something like drupal. please!

Comment: Nightmare, I'm sacking this CMS off, I shall try Drupal. Thank you for your help Schnalle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would be a excellent example of the use of recursion.  An array (with sub-arrays within it) defines each level, and a function loops, calling itself whenever it finds a new array to process.  As long as the function cleans up appropriately (closing the `</li> & </ol>`), it's largely automatic.

```
<?php
// I know which function I'd rather write....
$tree = array('Projects (Menu Level 1)',
              array('Project 1 (Menu Level 2)',
                    'Project 2 (Menu Level 2)',
                    'Project 3 (Menu Level 2)'),
              'News (Menu Level 1)',
              'Contact (Menu Level 1)');

// now quake beneath the power of this fully operational recursive function!
function olLiTree($tree)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($tree as $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            olLiTree($item);
        } else {
            echo '<li>', $item, '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
olLiTree($tree);  // kick off from the top level
```

Comment: You’re generating invalid HTML. The nested `<ul>` needs to be inside a `<li>`.

Comment: i'd avoid echoing inside the function, bad style imho.

Comment: Both very true.  But it's an example of recursive techniques, not of highest quality HTML & library design. I do those with more than 2 minutes notice.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was marked as accepted, since it doesn't actually solve the original problem (because sub-menu "ul" tags are outside the "li" tags instead of inside them). For a proper solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452305/php-function-generate-ul-li

Answer (score 3):

It appears Topbit already beat me to this, but mine is *slightly* differs in that it doesn't echo the value straight to the output stream, but saves it in a variable that you may `echo` at your convenience:

```
<?php

function GenerateMenu($arr)
{
    $output = "<ul>\n";
    foreach($arr as $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $output .= "<li>\n" . GenerateMenu($val, $output) . "</li>\n";
        }
        else {
            $output .= "<li>" . $val . "</li>\n";
        }
    }
    $output .= "</ul>\n";
    return $output;
}

$html = GenerateMenu($menu);

?>
```

**Edit:**

Thanks Gumbo and Topbit, now that I'm on my machine with PHP installed, I have tested it and it works fine.

Comment: replacing +'s with the string concatenation '.' does make it work.

Comment: You’re generating invalid HTML. The nested `<ul>` needs to be inside a `<li>`.

Comment: PHP string concatenation is . not +. And yes, a function should imo generally not output any data directly.

Answer (score 3):

A simple function is all you need.

```
function unorderedList($val)
{
    if (is_array($val)) {
        return '<ul><li>' . 
                implode('</li><li>', 
                    array_map('unorderedList', $val)) . 
            '</li></ul>';
    } else {
        return $val;
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
$menu = array('Projects (Menu Level 1)',
              array('Project 1 (Menu Level 2)',
                    'Project 2 (Menu Level 2)',
                    'Project 3 (Menu Level 2)'),
              'News (Menu Level 1)',
              'Contact (Menu Level 1)');


echo unorderedList($menu);
```

Comment: Thanks OIS, I understand that this is all I need now. However I do not have the knowledge to implement this as I would need to take into account other variables such as $pagenum, $menu, $selected, $extension, $set, which are used. I wish i could simply alter something in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this outputs the correct HTML structure.

```
function GenerateMenu($arr)
{
foreach($arr as $val) {
    if (next($arr)) { $nextitem = current($arr); }
    if (is_array($val)) {
        $output .= "\n<ul>\n" . GenerateMenu($val, $output) . "</ul>\n</li>\n\n";
    }
    elseif (is_array($nextitem)) { $output .= "<li>" . $val; }
    else { $output .= "<li>" . $val . "</li>\n"; }
}
return $output;
}
$html = GenerateMenu($menu);
echo("<ul>\n" . $html . '</ul>');
```

Same test code as above:

```
$menu = array('Projects (Menu Level 1)',
          array('Project 1 (Menu Level 2)',
                'Project 2 (Menu Level 2)',
                'Project 3 (Menu Level 2)'),
          'News (Menu Level 1)',
          'Contact (Menu Level 1)');
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this utilizing the PHP DOMDocument class. It will create your list as long and as deep as the list you give it using one simple and easy to follow loop. If you want it organized, just ask your database for the list sorted by title (or whatever) first.
It assumes your query object data is contained in $menu_categories and it at least has properties of ->id ->parent_id & ->title (change to your needs)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$dom->loadHTML("<html>");


$root = $dom->createElement('ul');
$root->setAttribute('class', 'menu');
$dom->appendChild($root);


foreach($menu_categories as $count => $category){
    $pid = $category->parent_id;
    $parent = $dom->getElementById('simple-li-'.$pid);

    if($parent != null){

        $ul = $dom->getElementById('simple-ul-'.$pid);

        if($ul == null){
            $ul = $dom->createElement('ul');
            $ul->setAttribute('id', 'simple-ul-'.$pid);
            $parent->appendChild($ul);
        }
        $target = $ul;

    }else{ 
        $target = $root;
    }   

    $li = $dom->createElement('li', $category->title);
    $li->setAttribute('id', 'simple-li-'.$category->id);
    $target->appendChild($li);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML($root);
return;
```

Here's the commented version...

```
/**
 * This is pure and simple PHP!
 * @author Jamin Szczesny - Mar 2014
 * Assuming you have a returned query list of related rows named... 
 *  $menu_categories (the list can be in any order)
 * and it has valid attributes of.. 
 * ->id (category id)
 * ->title  (category title\name)
 * ->parent_id (categories parent)
 * 
 */

$dom = new DOMDocument();//create a document
$dom->validateOnParse = true;//this is a must
$dom->loadHTML("<html>");//you must load some valid html

//add a root list to the dom
$root = $dom->createElement('ul');
$root->setAttribute('class', 'menu');
$dom->appendChild($root);

//loop through all of your category rows
foreach($menu_categories as $count => $category){
    $pid = $category->parent_id;
    $parent = $dom->getElementById('simple-li-'.$pid);

    //see if we found a parent
    if($parent != null){ //parent found...
        //look for a ul within the parent
        $ul = $dom->getElementById('simple-ul-'.$pid);

        //check to see if that ul exists
        if($ul == null){//ul not created yet so create one
            $ul = $dom->createElement('ul');
            $ul->setAttribute('id', 'simple-ul-'.$pid);
            $parent->appendChild($ul);
        }
        $target = $ul;

    }else{ //no parent found...
        $target = $root;
    }   
    //create this list item
    $li = $dom->createElement('li', $category->title);
    $li->setAttribute('id', 'simple-li-'.$category->id);
    $target->appendChild($li);
}
//output only the html from our list
echo $dom->saveHTML($root);
return;
```