# How to make a Nested List from array in PHP (noob)

Tags: php, arrays, list, nested

I have an app that users choose items and then it fills a table that has two columns in it:  Category and Items.  Its something like this:

```
Category  | Items 
-----------------
PET       | Dog Food
HEALTH    | Tooth Brush
PET       | Cat Food
COLD FOOD | Steak
COLD FOOD | Eggs
```

In my select statement I order the data by Category then by Items and I am using a WHILE loop to drop the data into an array.

```
while($listItems = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
    $myArray[] = array("category" => $listItems["Category"],
                       "item"     => $listItems["Name"]);
}
```

When I do a print_r($myArray);  I get something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [category] => Cold Food [item] => Steak )
        [1] => Array ( [category] => Food      [item] => Eggs )
        [2] => Array ( [category] => Health    [item] => Tooth Brush )
        [3] => Array ( [category] => Pet       [item] => Cat Food )
        [4] => Array ( [category] => Pet       [item] => Dog Food ) )
```

What I am wanting to do is output the data into a nested list something like this.

- Cold Food
  - Steak
  - Eggs
- Health
  - Tooth Brush
- Pet
  - Cat Food
  - Dog Food

Any help is welcomed!  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function that creates a nested ul li?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753853/php-function-that-creates-a-nested-ul-li)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
while($listItems = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
    $cat  = $listItems['Category'];
    $name = $listItems['Name'];

    if(!isset($myArray[$cat]))
      $myArray[$cat] = array();

    $myArray[$cat][] = $name;
}
```

Then, to output it you'd do this:

```
$buffer = '<ul>';
foreach($myArray as $cat => $items) {
   $buffer .= "<li>$cat</li><li><ul>";
   foreach($items as $item) {
      $buffer .= "<li>$item</li>";
   }
   $buffer .= '</ul></li>';
}
$buffer .= '</ul>';
echo $buffer;
```

Comment: Jacob you rock.  I been scratching my head on this for weeks and you nailed it in 13mins.  The only change I had to make was on the second "$buffer".  I changed it from $buffer .='<li><ul>'; to $buffer .='<li>'.$cat.'</li><ul>';

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. The idea is to reorganize your data into a more convenient form, namely to have the items indexed by category.

#### Code

```
<?php
    $items = array
    (
        array('category' => 'Cold Food', 'item' => 'Steak'),
        array('category' => 'Food', 'item' => 'Eggs'),
        array('category' => 'Health', 'item' => 'Tooth Brush'),
        array('category' => 'Pet', 'item' => 'Cat Food'),
        array('category' => 'Pet', 'item' => 'Dog Food'),
    );

    // Group the items by category.
    $itemsByCategory = array();

    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
        $category = $item['category'];
        $name     = $item['item'];

        if (!array_key_exists($category, $itemsByCategory))
            $itemsByCategory[$category] = array();

        $itemsByCategory[$category][] = $name;
    }

    // Output nested lists for the items.
?>  <ul>
<?php foreach ($itemsByCategory as $category => $items)
      {
?>        <li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($category); ?>

              <ul>
<?php           foreach ($items as $item)
                {
?>                  <li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($item); ?></li>
<?php           }
?>            </ul>
          </li>
<?php }
?>  </ul>
```

#### Output

> - Cold Food
>
>   - Steak
> - Food
>
>   - Eggs
> - Health
>
>   - Tooth Brush
> - Pet
>
>   - Cat Food
>   - Dog Food

Comment: This would work, but don't you think it'd be DRYer to have a nested array?

Comment: doesn't `asort($items)` save you from creating an entire new array?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
//establish $vlink before
$query = 'select distinct (category) from list';
$result = mysql_query($query,$vlink);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
    $query1 = "select items from list where category = ".$row[0];
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1,$vlink);

    echo '<h1>'.$row[0].'</h1>';
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        echo '<h2>'.$row1[0].'</h2>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
while($listItems = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
{
     $myArray[$listItems["Category"]][] = $listItems["Name"] 
}
```